# CodeIgniter ActiveRecord query large tables causes MySQL to freeze

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I'm trying to fetch all the customers and their remarks + products and treatments ... in one query.

The following query causes the MySQL database to crash on the server even though the following tables...

> remarks_treatments
>   remarks_arrangements
>   remarks_products

I only have around 100.000 rows, which should be no problem for MySQL.

Here is a screenshot of the query.

[image]

I can't even print the...

```
$this->db->last_query()
```

... to paste it into PHPMyAdmin for optimisation/debugging because it causes the whole database and website to freeze.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try $this->db->last_query(); after  $Q = $this->db->get();

Comment: I did that already, but it never reaches that point. :(

Comment: this is a little trick i used to do when things like this happen change the name of the table to customers1 so its gonna throw an error with the query
$this->db->from('customers1 c');

Comment: Hahah, genius! Thanks a lot, So simple, yet so useful!

Comment: glad to help, upgrade your question after you test the query maybe I might be able to help

Comment: Tomorrow as soon as I'm back at work :)